# get total from two different datasets into a third different tablix ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Here I am, again with another doubt.

Here is my problem:

I have a report where I show ALL the incomes and expenses of the company for the last two days, which i managed by placing a column group grouping the columns by the date

Originally, the report contained a single matrix with both incomes and expenses fed by a dataset that points to the company cube applying the following filter expression

```
=IIF(Fields!Fecha.Value=Parameters!FechaHoy.Value or Fields!Fecha.Value = Parameters!DiaAnterior.Value,true,false)
```

- FechaHoy = date sent via report parameter input
- FechaAyer = date
  parameter minus one day

and the filter value set to

```
=true
```

So far so good. Today, the upper management decided to split it into three matrix. One for incomes and other two for expenses (one for each expense category), so i startet with this

[initial report layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgFfn.png)

I created two new datasets for each one of the expense categories with the same filters, and now i'm here

[current report layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2EUT.png)

THE THING IS... as you can see, there is a "Total Destino" independent table where i have to add the totals of the second and third matrix in the image I added, but, as I already said I have to show the last two days, so i also have to partially add the total of each day (which are column grouped by date)

I'm pretty sured that there's also a better and more efficient way to manage what I did with the three matrices but the main issue which needs your assistance is how do i add the totals of the second and third matrices.

I already tried with

```
=Sum(Fields!Saldo.Value, "Informacion_Destino") + Sum(Fields!Saldo.Value, "Info_InvTesoreria")
```

but it adds the two days and repeat it for the two days. I also tried with **ReportItems!TextBox + ReportItems!TextBox** but the preview loads sends me an error message.

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Comment: what about reportitems!textbox.value+reportitems!textbox2.value

Comment: same thing with the error

Comment: Can you explicitly convert it to an integer or decimal and see what it does? Say for example cint(reportitems!textbox.value)+cint(reportitems!textbox2.value).. just stating the obvious here.. ensure your sum cell for each tablix is named textbox and textbox2 respectively.. (call it what ever you want, but ensure you use that name in the formula) .. just saying..

Answer (score 0):

Like Harry stated already out you can use for your overall total the following expression for the `Tesoreria Subtotal + Destino Subtotal` :

```
=ReportItems!TesoreriaSubtotal.Value + ReportItems!DestinoSubtotal.Value
```

This would give you the overall total for all days. Now if you just have to show the last two days you can add a tablix filter, like this:

```
'Expression
=IIF(CDate(Fields!YourDate.Value) < DateAdd("d", -2, Now()), True, False)

'Format
=Boolean

'Value
=False
```

Comment: An error ocurred during local report processing. Failed to evaluate the FilterExpression of the Tablix

Comment: I also ran some tests using the same dataset filter in the tablix but still no luck. It shows on both days the sum of the last day